# Multiple inheritance and Super

Tags: python

Why does this only work if I remove `config` from `__init__` in `Second`?

```
class First(object):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__(config)
        print("first", config)

class Second(object):
    def __init__(self, config): # <-- works only if I remove config
        super().__init__(config)
        print("second", config)

class Third(First, Second):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__(config)
        print("third", config)
        
Third({"name": "alex"})

=> second {'name': 'alex'}
=> first {'name': 'alex'}
=> third {'name': 'alex'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what's wrong:

```
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

`Second`'s parent class is `object`, and you're calling its `__init__` with an extra argument.

`super()` only gives you the first parent class, which makes it generally not helpful (and frequently just plain confusing) when you're doing multiple inheritance.  If you fix the code to eliminate the errors from calling `object.__init__(config)` you get:

```
class First:  # note that in modern Python you don't need to give object as the parent
    def __init__(self, config):
        print("first", config)

class Second:
    def __init__(self, config):
        print("second", config)

class Third(First, Second):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__(config)
        print("third", config)
        
Third({"name": "alex"})
```

```
first {'name': 'alex'}
third {'name': 'alex'}
```

because your `super().__init__` call only calls `First`.  Instead you probably want to explicitly call each parent class's constructor:

```
class Third(First, Second):
    def __init__(self, config):
        First.__init__(self, config)
        Second.__init__(self, config)
        print("third", config)
```

```
first {'name': 'alex'}
second {'name': 'alex'}
third {'name': 'alex'}
```

Comment: "super() only gives you the first parent class, which makes it generally not helpful (and frequently just plain confusing) when you're doing multiple inheritance." Um, it's **entire purpose** is to enable cooperative multiple inheritance.